# XSLT help to include a field in an XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Rowsets>
    <Rowset>
        <Columns>
            <Column Description="DrilldownDepth" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="DrilldownDepth" SQLDataType="4" SourceColumn="DrilldownDepth"/>
            <Column Description="ABC" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="ABC" SQLDataType="4" SourceColumn="ABC"/>
            <Column Description="DEF" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="DEF" SQLDataType="-1" SourceColumn="DEF"/>
            <Column Description="PQR" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="PQR" SQLDataType="-1" SourceColumn="PQR"/>
        </Columns>
        <Row>
            <DrilldownDepth>1</DrilldownDepth>
            <ABC>25</ABC>
            <DEF>DDD</DEF>
            <PQR>PPP</PQR>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <DrilldownDepth>1</DrilldownDepth>
            <ABC>16</ABC>
            <DEF>AAA</DEF>
            <PQR>BBB</PQR>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <DrilldownDepth>1</DrilldownDepth>
            <ABC>19</ABC>
            <DEF>SEE</DEF>
            <PQR>HELP</PQR>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

Now I need to add  in every Row. hence my XML will look like following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Rowsets>
    <Rowset>
        <Columns>
            <Column Description="DrilldownDepth" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="DrilldownDepth" SQLDataType="4" SourceColumn="DrilldownDepth"/>
            <Column Description="ABC" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="ABC" SQLDataType="4" SourceColumn="ABC"/>
            <Column Description="DEF" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="DEF" SQLDataType="-1" SourceColumn="DEF"/>
            <Column Description="PQR" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="PQR" SQLDataType="-1" SourceColumn="PQR"/>
        </Columns>
        <Row>
            <DrilldownDepth>1</DrilldownDepth>
            <ABC>25</ABC>
            <DEF>DDD</DEF>
            <PQR>PPP</PQR>
            <XYZ></XYZ>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <DrilldownDepth>1</DrilldownDepth>
            <ABC>16</ABC>
            <DEF>AAA</DEF>
            <PQR>BBB</PQR>
            <XYZ></XYZ>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <DrilldownDepth>1</DrilldownDepth>
            <ABC>19</ABC>
            <DEF>SEE</DEF>
            <PQR>HELP</PQR>
            <XYZ></XYZ>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

How can I achive this using transform / XSLT?

I tried various XSLT but somehow I am not able to achieve it.

Soham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Template #1 -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Template #2 -->
  <xsl:template match="Row">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
      <XYZ></XYZ>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...when applied to the original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Rowsets>
  <Rowset>
    <Columns>
      <Column Description="DrilldownDepth" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="DrilldownDepth" SQLDataType="4" SourceColumn="DrilldownDepth"/>
      <Column Description="ABC" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="ABC" SQLDataType="4" SourceColumn="ABC"/>
      <Column Description="DEF" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="DEF" SQLDataType="-1" SourceColumn="DEF"/>
      <Column Description="PQR" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="PQR" SQLDataType="-1" SourceColumn="PQR"/>
    </Columns>
    <Row>
      <DrilldownDepth>1</DrilldownDepth>
      <ABC>25</ABC>
      <DEF>DDD</DEF>
      <PQR>PPP</PQR>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <DrilldownDepth>1</DrilldownDepth>
      <ABC>16</ABC>
      <DEF>AAA</DEF>
      <PQR>BBB</PQR>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <DrilldownDepth>1</DrilldownDepth>
      <ABC>19</ABC>
      <DEF>SEE</DEF>
      <PQR>HELP</PQR>
    </Row>
  </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

...produces the desired result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Rowsets>
  <Rowset>
    <Columns>
      <Column Description="DrilldownDepth" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="DrilldownDepth" SQLDataType="4" SourceColumn="DrilldownDepth"/>
      <Column Description="ABC" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="ABC" SQLDataType="4" SourceColumn="ABC"/>
      <Column Description="DEF" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="DEF" SQLDataType="-1" SourceColumn="DEF"/>
      <Column Description="PQR" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="PQR" SQLDataType="-1" SourceColumn="PQR"/>
    </Columns>
    <Row>
      <DrilldownDepth>1</DrilldownDepth>
      <ABC>25</ABC>
      <DEF>DDD</DEF>
      <PQR>PPP</PQR>
      <XYZ/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <DrilldownDepth>1</DrilldownDepth>
      <ABC>16</ABC>
      <DEF>AAA</DEF>
      <PQR>BBB</PQR>
      <XYZ/>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <DrilldownDepth>1</DrilldownDepth>
      <ABC>19</ABC>
      <DEF>SEE</DEF>
      <PQR>HELP</PQR>
      <XYZ/>
    </Row>
  </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

**Explanation:**

- Template #1 is the Identity Template; it copies all nodes/attributes as-is (unless it gets overridden by subsequent templates).
- Template #2 copies every `<row>` element, processes its children (via the Identity Template), and adds the desired `<XYZ>` node.

Comment: WOW, that was fast !! .. And it does suffice my requirements :) .. thanks a ton for the help ..

Comment: My pleasure, @Soham! Remember, you can mark an answer correct by toggling the question mark symbol near the up/down-vote count. :)